# How to connect to HTTPS connection to use an API in Python?

Tags: python, api, rest

**This is the requirement from the API's documentation**

- A HTTPS connection is needed to use the API. This means that you will require a secure SSL/TLS connection to be able to communicate with our API Server.

**This is the *Curl* command of getting the clients in their documentation**

```
curl -i -X GET -H "X-KEYALI-API:{API_KEY}" -u {API_USERNAME}:{API_PASSWORD} https://aliphia.com/v1/api_public/clients/
```

So, I need to implement the same thing in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-KEYALI-API': '{API_KEY}',
}

response = requests.get('https://aliphia.com/v1/api_public/clients/', headers=headers, auth=('{API_USERNAME}', '{API_PASSWORD}'))
```